# How to model tournaments database into a SQL in django

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I want to model a tournament database to store data of online games
My question is: How to create a model in **relationship** database to store all this types of tournaments? (such as, league of legends tournament, dota 2 tournament)
For example, a tournament can have 8 teams or 5 teams.

This is the sketch I created in my mind. What things do you suggest (especially I need help with relationships of tables).
Also how to keep team 1 and team 2 in the match table (such as, scores, winner, loser)

i thought;
Game database

```
game_id,name
```

Player database

```
player_id,name,surname,country,Game(FK).. ( and some other fields)
```

Team database

```
team_id,name,country,game,Player(ManyToMany).. ( and some other fields)
```

Match database

```
match_id,name,match_game,match_map,team1,team2,winner,loser,date,duration,score1,score2.. ( and some other fields)
```

Tournament database

```
tournament_id,tournament_name,tournament_game,Match(ManyToMany).. ( and some other fields)
```

Comment: Maybe this helps : https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_models/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create something like this in `[app_name]/models.py`

```
from django.db import models


class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Match(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    match_game = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    match_map = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    match_teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    loser = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    duration = models.DurationField()
    winning_score = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    losing_score = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Some things to note:

- You do not need to create ID fields, Django does this for you automatically.
- A Many-to-Many field can often be replaced with a One-to-One field on the other model, for instance instead of many matches having many games, each game is part of one match. This may or may not work in your particular use case.
- I have changed some field names (such as `score_1` being replaced with `winning_score`) because I feel they are more clear, assuming I have correctly understood their purpose.
- There are some fields (`Tournament.tournament_game`, `Player.country`) for which I used `CharField` but would be better served with a `ForeingKey` field to a separate model.

This also assumes that you do not need different fields for different types of tournament (League of Legends, DOTA). If you do need this you could achieve it with different models that inherit from an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance):

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class DOTA2Game(Game):
    dota_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class LeagueOfLegendsGame(Game):
    lol_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

In this example `DOTA2Game` and `LeagueOfLegendsGame` both inherit from `Game` and therefore have both a `name` and a `match` field as well as their custom fields. Setting `abstract = True` in the meta class of Game prevents it existing as a separate table within the database.

Comment: Should i do match_teams1 = models.ManyToManyField(Team) and  match2_teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team) or only  match_teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team) is enough ? ( And thank you for help) [ my last question can you help me the fields of class Tournament(models.Model):

Comment: I think a single ManyToManyField is the best way to go as match_teams1 would imply that ordering is significant when I assume it is not. Also it is important to think about how you will use the information in the database, not just how you will store it. With a single ManyToManyField you can use `match.teams.all()` to return a queryset of teams involved in the match. Otherwise you would have to create a list or tuple (`teams = (match.team_1, match.team2)`. I am not sure what you are asking about the tournament fields, Was your comment cut short?

Comment: i solved tournament field. However, exactly what I want to ask about the match; team1, team1score and team2, team2score thought like that. I mean, how can I do this in manytomany relationships?

Comment: This would best be done using a [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). Essentially this is a separate model with a `match` field and a `team` field, which are foreign keys to thos models, and other fields with additional information such as score.