# Player-Team model relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I am building a database to show the tournaments of online games. I have three questions;

first one, Which method should i use

```
class Player(models.Model):
        team=models.ForeignKey(Team,related_name='player',verbose_name='Team')
```

OR

```
 class Team(models.Model):
        player=models.ManyToManyField(Player)
```

third; my tables between the team and the player does this look correct?
Last; After these tables I will make the tables between the match and the tournament. What should be the relationship between the match and the team

```
class OnlineGame(models.Model):
    game_name=models.CharField(max_length=120)


class Team(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name="Takım ismi")
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=120,unique=True)
    bio=models.TextField()
    country=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    logo=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='team')
    background=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='team')
    extra=models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=150)
    website=models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=120)
    game=models.ManyToManyField(OnlineGame)#manytomany because team have one or more online game team (for example sk gaming have lol and counter-strike team

    def get_unique_slug(self):
        slug=slugify(self.name.replace('ı','i'))
        unique_slug=slug
        counter=1
        while Team.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug='{}-{}'.format(slug,counter)
            counter+=1
        return slug

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name


class PlayerGameRole(models.Model):
    role=models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Player(models.Model):
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True,max_length=120)
    nickname=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    picture=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='player')
    country=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    role=models.ManyToManyField(PlayerGameRole)
    team=models.ForeignKey(Team,related_name='player',verbose_name='Team')
    twitch=models.URLField(null=True,blank=True)
    facebook=models.URLField(null=True,blank=True)
    twitter=models.URLField(null=True,blank=True)
    extra=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    game=models.ManyToManyField(Game)

    def get_unique_slug(self):
        slug=slugify(self.nickname.replace('ı','i'))
        unique_slug=slug
        counter=1
        while Player.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug='{}-{}'.format(slug,counter)
            counter+=1
        return slug


    def age(self):
        import datetime
        return int((datetime.date.today() - self.birthday).days / 365.25)
```

Comment: Does a `Player` belongs to one team, or multiple teams.

Comment: I get the feeling you're having SO design your entire DB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56888493/how-to-model-tournaments-database-into-a-sql-in-django]
Anyways. You should probably go with the `player=models.ManyToManyField(Player)`, since I'm assuming a user can play different games, and thus be in different teams. If a user has to create a new player for a new game, go with the other option.

Comment: thank you for your help i just want to check to if any mistake. ( Because I'm new in coding)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ManyToMany field type for team field in Player model, if player can be in few teams at the same time. The relationship between the match and the team should be ManyToMany too because a team can play several matches and match can be played by several teams.